# sql stored procedure parameter problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this weird problem with one of my SP's. 
I have a SP and one of the parameters is nvarchar type. 
and I am declaring the parameter, I am including value too, but when I am running there is no data returned. 
short example:

```
 @BookName nvarchar = null
```

Then in the where clause I have:

```
AND (o.BookName = @BookName OR @BookName IS NULL)
```

No data is returned.

But when I am doing:

```
AND (o.BookName = 'SQL Book' OR @BookName IS NULL)
```

I am getting the proper results.
Just to let you know that the field is no FK.

Any ideas what can be the reason?
Thanks

UPDATE:
SP CONTENT:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedSearch]
(
    @StartTime datetime = null,
    @EndTime datetime = null,
    @CustomerEmail nvarchar(255) = null,    
    @BookName nvarchar = null
    )
     AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, o.OrderTotal FROM Nop_Order o    
    WHERE (o.CreatedOn > @StartTime OR @StartTime IS NULL)
    AND (o.CreatedOn < @EndTime OR @EndTime IS NULL)
    AND (o.ShippingEmail = @CustomerEmail OR @CustomerEmail IS NULL)
    AND (o.BookName = @BookName OR @BookName IS NULL)
    ORDER BY o.OrderID

    END
```

Comment: Generally a good idea to mention which database you're using. NVARCHAR and the syntax makes me think it's Microsoft SQL Server, but you should be specific.

Comment: Could you show the complete query?

Comment: Can you post more of the sproc and maybe a data sample?

Comment: @Ian Varley SQL Server 2008. I am sorry

Comment: I meant - can you post the code that calls it? I have no idea what you mean by "AdvancedSearch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
@BookName nvarchar = null
```

with

```
@BookName nvarchar(100) = null
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your stored proc definition, you're not giving your `@BookName` parameter any length - I think SQL Server will default to just 1 character in that case:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedSearch]
(
  @StartTime datetime = null,
  @EndTime datetime = null,
  @CustomerEmail nvarchar(255) = null,    
  @BookName nvarchar = null   ** no length given!!
)
```

Try to change that to a suitable length, e.g. `NVARCHAR(100)` or something

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedSearch]
(
  @StartTime datetime = null,
  @EndTime datetime = null,
  @CustomerEmail nvarchar(255) = null,    
  @BookName nvarchar(100) = null   ** define a length !!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is that you're not actually passing the parameter into the procedure from your client-side code. Make sure of that. You can also test the procedure entirely at the SQL side by running it ("EXEC myProcedure('SQL Book')") to see if you get the right answer that way; then you'll know it's a communication issue.

Comment: I am doing that too, whenever I will include the book parameter, I don't get data

Answer (score 0):

If calling from .NET then try

```
Dim param as New SqlParameter("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8)
```

> Or DBType.String

After you posted your update:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdvancedSearch] 
( 
    @StartTime datetime = null, 
    @EndTime datetime = null, 
    @CustomerEmail nvarchar(255) = null,     
    @BookName nvarchar = null 
    ) 
     AS 
    BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderID, o.OrderTotal FROM Nop_Order o     
    WHERE (o.CreatedOn > @StartTime OR @StartTime IS NULL) 
    AND (o.CreatedOn < @EndTime OR @EndTime IS NULL) 
    AND (o.ShippingEmail = @CustomerEmail OR @CustomerEmail IS NULL) 
    AND (o.BookName = COALESCE(@BookName, BookName))
    ORDER BY o.OrderID 

    END
```

Comment: if (!bookName.Equals(string.Empty))
                {
                    commAdvanced.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bookName;
                }
                else
                {
                    commAdvanced.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }

Comment: that's how I am trying, I am sorry, I don't know how to put the text in a code block